# Undefined array key, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

```
Warning: Undefined array key "image" in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogg\admin\include\edit_post.php on line 33

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogg\admin\include\edit_post.php on line 33

Warning: Undefined array key "image" in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogg\admin\include\edit_post.php on line 34

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogg\admin\include\edit_post.php on line 34
```

[image: [code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfWNw.png)]

I was expecting to be able to update the image but that is not working out. Also, in the update, there is no where to click to choose a different image.

[image: code snippet 2]

Comment: Please don't post picture of code

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue, and then [edit] your post. As you're new please also take the [tour] to ensure you understand how stackoverflow works. Thanks

Comment: The "image" key does not exist inside `$_FILES`. You should check what `$_FILES` actually contains.

Answer (score 4):

You can never trust an array index to exist (no mechanism in PHP can enforce that). A general good practice when accessing an array is to either :

- Check if it exists beforehand

```php
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
  $post_image = $_FILES['image'];
} else {
  // handle error
}
```

- Provide a fallback value when it doesn't

```php
$post_image = $_FILES['image'] ?? '';
```

In your case, the index certainly does not exist because you submitted the form without uploading a file in the "image" field. If you consider the file to be mandatory, the first snippet is better. If it's not, the second one is shorter and easier.